# How to append row to html table using javascript?

Tags: javascript, url, google-chrome-extension, html-table, append

I'm creating an google chrome extension and trying to log data in html table. I am currently having trouble trying to get rows to append to my html table. I'm trying to get it to where everytime the user visits a new url another row is added to the table.

[Picture of chrome extension](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wdQvG.png)

Below is my current code:

***Manifest.json***

```
{
    //Required naming
    "name" : "Activity logger",
    "version": "1.0",
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "description": "This support includes the development of a  Chrome Browser Activity Logger.",
    
    "content_scripts": [
        {
            "matches": ["<all_urls>"],
            "js": ["content.js", "popup.js"]
        }
        
     ],
     
    
     "browser_action": {
        "default_icon": "act.png",
        "default_title": "Activity",
        "default_popup": "popup.html"
        
     },
     "background": {
        "scripts": ["background.js"]
        
     },
     
     
     "permissions": ["tabs", "storage"]
    
    
    
    

}
```

***popup.html***

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>
        Activity Logger
    </title>
    <style>
    *{
        color:#2b2b2b;
        font-family: "Roboto Condensed";
     }
        table{ width:40%;}
        th{ text-align:left; color:#4679bd}
        tbody > tr:nth-of-type(even) { background-color:#daeaff;)
        button( cursor:pointer; margin-top:1rem;)
         
    </style>
</head>
<body>

    <script src="popup.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
    
    <h2>Activity Logger</h2>
    
    
    <table id = "tableID" border="1">
        <!--Example table header row with the user, url visited, and time they visited the url etc-->
  <tr>
      <!--categories-->
    <th>Browser</th>
    <th>Timestamp</th>
    <th>URL</th>
    <th>Protocol</th> 
    <th>Downloaded File Names</th> 
    <th>Description</th>
      
  </tr>
  <tr id='myRow'>
      <!--1st row-->
    <td>Google</td>
    <td>000000</td>
    <td>https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask</td>
    <td>example</td>
    <td>example</td>
    <td>example</td>
  </tr>
     <!--Goal is to append to this table-->
 

</table>
   <!--when clicked it, ID uses function, exportTableToCSV to download file-->
<a id="click-this">
    <u> Save as CSV </u>
    </a>

</body>
</html>
```

***popup.js***

```
//loads element url on page--draft
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
   
  const bg = chrome.extension.getBackgroundPage()
  Object.keys(bg.bears).forEach(function (url) {
    const div = document.createElement('div')
    div.textContent = `${url}`
    document.body.appendChild(div)
    
  })


}, false)


// creates ID to export table to csv--works
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  document.getElementById("click-this").addEventListener("click", exportTableToCSV);
 
    
});

//--underwork--
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  document.getElementById("tableID").addEventListener("click", addRow);
 
    
});


//function to append row to HTML table --underwork--
function addRow() {
        //perhaps need an for loop for every page visited 
        
    
    //get html table
        // Append product to the table
    var table = document.getElementByID("tableID");
    
    // add new empty row to the table
                  // 1 = in the top (say you wanna have the most recent link visited at the top row after the header) 
                  // table.rows.length = the end
                  // table.rows.length/2+1 = the center (probably not useful for you)

                  var newRow = table.insertRow(1);
                  
                  // add cells to the row
                  var nameCell = newRow.insertCell(0);
                  var urlCell = newRow.insertCell(1);
                  var timeCell = newRow.insertCell(2);
                  
                  // add the data to the cells
                  nameCell.innerHTML = USERNAME; 
                  urlCell.innerHTML = URL_VISITED; 
                  timeCell .innerHTML = TIMESTAM;
            }



//perhaps add row using JQuery--underwork
/*function addRowUsingJquery() {
    // Get a reference to your table
    let table = document.querySelector('#tableID');
    
 
    // Build the row
        let template = `
                <tr>
                        <td>${USERNAME}</td>
                        <td>${URL_VISITED}</td>
                        <td>${TIMESTAMP}</td>
                </tr>`;

    // Add the row to the end of the table
        table.innerHTML += template; 
}
*/
                           

//function to for onClick function--works
function downloadCSV(csv, filename) {
    var csvFile;
    var downloadLink;
    
    csvFile = new Blob([csv], {type:"text/csv"});
                       
                       
    downloadLink = document.createElement("a");
    downloadLink.download = filename;
    downloadLink.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(csvFile);
    downloadLink.style.display = "none";
    downloadLink.setAttribute("download", "data.csv");
    
    document.body.appendChild(downloadLink);
    
    
    downloadLink.click();
}

//function to export HTML table to csv file--works
function exportTableToCSV(filename) {
    var csv = [];
    var rows = document.querySelectorAll("table tr");
    
    for(var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
        var row = [], cols = rows[i].querySelectorAll("td, th");
        for(var j=0; j < cols.length; j++)
            row.push(cols[j].innerText);
        
        csv.push(row.join(","));
    }   
       
   
    //download csv file
    downloadCSV(csv.join("\n"), filename);
    
    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe when you use insertRow, the html of the table needs to have a tbody

http://jsfiddle.net/4sR2G/
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLTableElement/insertRow

So the html table should be in the format of:

```
<table id="tableID">
   <thead>
      <tr>
         <th>Browser</th>
         <th>Timestamp</th>
         <th>URL</th>
         <th>Protocol</th>
         <th>Downloaded File Names</th>
         <th>Description</th>
      </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody id="tbodyID">
      <tr>
         <td>Google</td>
         <td>000000</td>
         <td>https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask</td>
         <td>example</td>
         <td>example</td>
         <td>example</td>
      </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
```

You can then change the JS to reflect these changes:

```
//function to append row to HTML table --underwork--
function addRow() {
        //perhaps need an for loop for every page visited 
        
    
    //get html table
        // Append product to the table
    var table = document.getElementById("tbodyID");
    
    // add new empty row to the table
                  // 1 = in the top (say you wanna have the most recent link visited at the top row after the header) 
                  // table.rows.length = the end
                  // table.rows.length/2+1 = the center (probably not useful for you)
                  // insertRow(0) as top of body (excludes head)
                  var newRow = table.insertRow(0);
                  
                  // add cells to the row
                  var nameCell = newRow.insertCell(0);
                  var urlCell = newRow.insertCell(1);
                  var timeCell = newRow.insertCell(2);
                  
                  // add the data to the cells
                  nameCell.innerHTML = USERNAME; 
                  urlCell.innerHTML = URL_VISITED; 
                  timeCell.innerHTML = TIMESTAM;
            }
```